# Is there a way to rescind a close vote?

Tags: discussion, voting, close-reasons

I voted to close [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64468/what-hidden-features-have-you-found-in-ios-6) question earlier today because I didn't realize iOS 6 had been released. I have since realized that I'm an idiot and should check things before blithely voting to close a perfectly fine question for a reason that no longer applies.

So: I'd like to rescind my close vote. Is there a way to do this? If there isn't, can one be added?

Comment: With respect to that question, I'm not ready to close it as a binding vote, but feel it would be more useful to the site with one answer that was CW like [this example](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23577/how-many-genius-mixes-are-there-in-itunes) If you read my edit notes on the question I describe some of what I see as wrong about "popularity contest" questions.

Comment: If you want to request this as a feature, please ask on the main meta. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ I'll leave this as a "can I do this" without the feature-request tag since it documents what we can do now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - votes time out and only get cleared if a moderator takes a binding action.

However, you can favorite the question and watch it and vote to reopen it should enough people cast close votes to actually close the question.

And of course, flagging it would be appropriate - just as if you saw any other question that was flagged and you felt in reality it was closed incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, since 15th July 2013. Click the close button again after voting to close and you have the option to retract your vote.

[image]